# How to add custom menu in blender in header?

Tags: python, interface, add-on, customization

I am trying to add custom menu and sub menu into this header strip consists of workspaces. How can i do it if i want to add a custom option after Scripting option?[image]

Comment: Hello ! In the API these are not called Menus but Workspaces (https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BlendDataWorkSpaces.html#bpy.types.BlendDataWorkSpaces and https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.WorkSpace.html#bpy.types.WorkSpace, and AFAIK you have to use an operator. You can eg duplicate the current one with `bpy.ops.workspace.duplicate()`

Comment: @Gorgious first of all thanks and actually i just meant about the row which consists of workspaces, can we add a custom option of ours either there or in the header next to Add and Object row.
I tried to achieve this but i can only find a way to add my custom as a sub menu of the given one but not as a new option directly into the bar. Sorry i am new to it so might mess up the names , let me know if i need to be more clear.